# Parse soap message

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I get soap message but cannot parse all value in parameter list.

refer : http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

I follow that but my data have multi value.It can parse only one.How can I do

**XML Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
        <m:ExecuteServiceResponse xmlns:m="http://com/myproject/sff/ws">
            <m:return>
                <java:ErrorMessage xmlns:java="java:com.myproject.sff.domain.gm.vo.ws"/>
                <java:ParameterList xmlns:java="java:com.myproject.sff.domain.gm.vo.ws">

                        <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>success</java:Name>
                            <java:Value xsi:nil="true"/>
                        </java:Parameter>   

                       <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>productID</java:Name>
                            <java:Value>T3452789</java:Value>
                        </java:Parameter>

                        <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>productName</java:Name>
                            <java:Value>some</java:Value>
                        </java:Parameter>

                </java:ParameterList>
            </m:return>
        </m:ExecuteServiceResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**My Code**

*main.java*

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("msg/input.xml");
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

    xsr.nextTag();


    while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("Parameter")) {

        xsr.nextTag();
    }

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parameter.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<Parameter> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Parameter.class);

    xsr.close();

    Parameter Parameter = jb.getValue();

    System.out.println(Parameter.Name);
    System.out.println(Parameter.Value);
```

*Parameter.java*

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parameter {

    @XmlElement(namespace="java:com.myproject.sff.domain.gm.vo.ws")
    String Name;
    @XmlElement(namespace="java:com.myproject.sff.domain.gm.vo.ws")
    String Value;

    @XmlElement(name = "Parameter")
      private List<Parameter> Parameter;         
      public List<Parameter> getCustomer (){
        if( Parameter == null ){
            Parameter = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
        }
        return Parameter;
      }

}
```

Comment: Please add the parser code and the Java model you used.

Comment: You should have "ParameterList.java" which holds list of Parameter objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just unmarshall elements like that, they have to be wrapped with some other element, for example:

```
<java:ParameterList xmlns:java="java:com.myproject.sff.domain.gm.vo.ws">
                     <java:ParList>
                        <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>success</java:Name>
                            <java:Value xsi:nil="true"/>
                        </java:Parameter>   

                       <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>productID</java:Name>
                            <java:Value>T3452789</java:Value>
                        </java:Parameter>

                        <java:Parameter>
                            <java:Name>productName</java:Name>
                            <java:Value>some</java:Value>
                        </java:Parameter>
                     <java:ParList>
                </java:ParameterList>
```

and then change your code to something like that:

```
 @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ParList")
 @XmlElement(name = "Parameter")
 private List<Parameter> Parameter;
```

I'm not entirely sure aobut that `<java:ParameterList>` around your Parameters, but maybe you can use it aswell.